# numba ctype matching with ndfilter

Tags: python, scipy, numba, ndimage

I am trying to use Numba `cfunc` as `scipy.LowLevelCallable` inside `ndi.generic_filter` however I am facing signature matching issue. If I set return type to `int16` it recognize as `short` if I set to `int32` or `intc` it says `long`. Both signatures cannot be matched. The matching problem is in return type

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from numba import cfunc, carray, types
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

@cfunc("intc (CPointer(float64),intp, CPointer(float64), voidptr)") #problematic
def myfunc(values_ptr, len_values, result, data):
    #some work here
    return 1

footprint = np.array([[0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1],[0, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)
from scipy import ndimage as ndi

a=np.random.random((100,100))
ndi.generic_filter(a, scipy.LowLevelCallable(myfunc.ctypes), footprint=footprint)
```

This is the Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid scipy.LowLevelCallable signature "long (double *, long, double *, void *)". Expected one of: ['int (double *, intptr_t, double *, void *)', 'int (double *, npy_intp, double *, void *)', 'int (double *, int, double *, void *)', 'int (double *, long, double *, void *)']
```

System specs (if related): Python  2.7.10 (32-bit), Numba 0.39.0

Comment: Which OS is this?

Comment: windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you ran into [this known issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2578). Specifically, there appears to be no way to produce the signature expected by `LowLevelCallable` with Numba on platforms where `int` and `long` are the same size (such as 64 bit flavors of Windows).

I suggest you support a fix on GitHub. In the meantime, your best bet is to pass the Numba functon directly into `generic_filter` and accept some function call overhead, or to wrap the function in a supported way, e.g. via Cython.

Comment: Thats exactly the issue. I guess wrapper has more overhead here compared to python mode. That was the reason I tried njit. I will still give it a shot. Thanks